# How do you automatically add foreign keys to an existing Rails database?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm new to Ruby, and joining an existing Ruby on Rails project trying to understand the database to rearchitect it.

If I generate a MySql diagram I see that Rails doesn't use foreign keys, making it impossible to analyse the diagram:
[image]

But Ruby understand table relationships obviously internally. Is there any script that can go through all the migrations .rb scripts and add foreign keys to them automatically?

Comment: All the information is coded in the models of your rails app, you can search for belongs_to and has_many here.

Comment: Not really sure what you mean "rails doesnt use foreign keys", and the text in your screenshot is too small to read.

Comment: It should be possible to write a script to do this without too much effort, but you won't be able to create foreign keys for polymorphic associations (where you have two columns: one with the id, and one with the model name) as this is not something you can do in MySQL (or any other database engine, AFAIK).

Comment: @max - Rails doesn't create foreign keys in the database. The screenshot is showing no lines between tables as there is no referential integrity in a Rails database.

Comment: @Carpetsmoker do you know of any existing code to get me started? I can't see any relationships in the migration scripts, I'm guessing they're hidden somewhere among the main app models.

Comment: @Richard I don't know of any scripts (although they may exist), but I know you can use `ActiveRecord::Reflection` to get this sort of information quite easily (see [`reflect_on_all_associations`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Reflection/ClassMethods.html#method-i-reflect_on_all_associations) for example). At the moment, I don't have time to write and debug a full script for this, but perhaps someone else has, or maybe this is enough to get you in the right direction ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the immigrant gem found at https://github.com/jenseng/immigrant to your Gemfile and then

```
rails generate immigration AddKeys
rake db:migrate
```

You will also need to include the foreigner gem if you are using an older version of Rails.

Answer (score 1):

The statement "Rails doesn't use foreign keys" is simply not true.

ActiveRecord does not require you to use foreign keys constraints for associations. It does however add foreign key constraints by default when you use the `references` and `belongs_to` migration macros.

```
rails g model thing other_thing:references
```

So if you are taking over a legacy project with no or little referential integrity that is the developers fault - not Rails. Don't blame the hammer when the carpenter is drunk.

Understanding when and how to use indices and constraints is actually quite difficult and building automation to do that may be an order of magnitude more complex than actually solving the task in the first place.

What you need to is actually look at the schema and models and see where the foreign keys should be added and create migrations to add those foreign keys.

Comment: Hmm... I don't think it's wise to compare not using DB constraints with "drunk" carpentry. Many consider it consistent with the "convention over configuration" midset of Rails to use relations and validations in the model instead, and thinking of the DB as a flat data store opens the developer up to other nonSQL DB options. The docs also mention foreign key constraints are "not required": http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html#foreign-keys